# Cuda API to render using Physically Based Rendering (PBR) in OpenGL-ES based project

Tags: opengl-es, pbr, cuda

I need to develop a OpenGL-ES based application to render a model using Physically based Rendering (PBR).
Do I need to use Cuda API to render the computation intense PBR rendering?

Is there any performance advantage of using CUDA in the OpenGL-ES project for PBR?

Comment: What does your profiling indicate, after your initial tests?

Comment: I have not used CUDA APIs now. I want to know if there is any advantage in terms of performance, functionality, memory usage in using CUDA APIs in an OpenGL ES project.

Comment: That sounds like a question whose answer could vary based on hardware and use case, ie. one that you can answer better by profiling your particular use case on your target hardware.